# Passing Parameters to KnpMenuBundle-MenuBuilder (registered as service)

Tags: php, symfony, twig, knpmenubundle

I want to pass an additional parameter `{'id': '555'}` from a twig-template to the `$options-parameter` in the `MenuBuilder.php`.
The twig looks like:

```
...
{{ knp_menu_render('createSwitchButton', {'id': '555'} )  }}
...
```

The `service.yml` looks like:

```
 RochPartyplaner.menu_builder:
    class: RochPartyplaner\PartyBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
    arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]

 RochPartyplaner.menu.createSwitchButton:
    class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem 
    factory_service: RochPartyplaner.menu_builder
    factory_method: createSwitchButton
    arguments: ["@request", []]
    scope: request 
    tags:
        - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: createSwitchButton }
```

And the `MenuBuilder.php` looks like:

```
...    
public function createSwitchButton(Request $request,array $options)
{
    $menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');

    $menu->addChild($options['id'], array('route' => 'login'));
    ...

    return $menu;
}
```

But: in the `Builder`, `$options['id']` is unknown. I think the arguments-statement in the `service.yml` is wrong.

Would somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention a version of KnpBundle. In v2.* version [according to documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#rendering-menus) you can do like this

```
{% set menuItem = knp_menu_get('TestProductBundle:Builder:mainMenu', [], {'some_option': 'my_value'}) %}

{{ knp_menu_render(menuItem) }}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't reply to the question. Where can you retrieve the values of options?

Comment: class BuyerMenuBuilder extends ContainerAware {

    public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
  see options array for example

Comment: So, it looks like that is the only solution: not using the menu as a service. Too bad.